# iOS Detect Drag Stopped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uislider, uitouch

Super simple question that I'm stumped on:

I'm using a `UISlider` that should detect when a user drags (but doesn't *tap*) the thumb of the slider. This works and the thumb can obviously be dragged, but I need to be notified when the drag event stops. Is there a control event that I'm not seeing that will allow me to differentiate the stop of a drag and the stop of a tap?

Or is there some simple way of accomplishing this in the `touchesEnded:` method?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(slidingStopped:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void) slidingStopped:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"stopped sliding");
}
```

Comment: I know this is ancient but this is not complete. You need to send the message for the UIControlEventTouchUpOutside as well, otherwise the user could drag their finger outside of the control bounds and then let go and you wouldn't get the message.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but here's what I did. It can be adapted to the UISlider problem.

```
BOOL buttonDidMove = NO;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouchUpInside) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Tap Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)buttonTouchUpInside
{
    if (buttonDidMove) {
        buttonDidMove = NO;
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"buttonTouchUpInside");
    [self initNetworkCommunication];
}

- (void)buttonMoved:(UIButton *)control withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"buttonMoved");
    buttonDidMove = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:control] anyObject];
    control.center = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ratingScale addTarget:self action:@selector(slideEnds:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
```

where ratingScale would be your sample UISlider & slideEnds would be your sample selector to be fired for the above event.

The touchDragInside criteria ensures that the selector is only fired as long as you keep dragging. It does not fire if you just register taps on the slider thumb.

Comment: And how can I detect if the user's finger lifts after dragging vs. simply touching?